# Message gradle build

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

При компиляции возникла следующая ошибка, как избавится от нее ?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
    File1: /home/fedia/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.2.2/285cb9c666f0f0f3dd8a1be04e1f457eb7b15113/jackson-annotations-2.2.2.jar
    File2: /home/fedia/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/2.2.2/d20be6a5ddd6f8cfd36ebf6dea329873a1c41f1b/jackson-core-2.2.2.jar
    File3: /home/fedia/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.2.2/3c8f6018eaa72d43b261181e801e6f8676c16ef6/jackson-databind-2.2.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ошибка дублирования файлов. Гугл говорит что, согласно [вот этому ответу с en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593694/3212712) вам надо вот это добавить в ваш `build.gradle`

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
}
```